# Spring Boot. 500 error after PostMapping Controller return statement

Tags: spring-boot, redirect

I have simple code for 2 controllers

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/createPost") 
public String createUserPost(@PathVariable("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("person", personDao.getPersonById(id));
    modelMap.addAttribute("userDB", personDao.getUsrById(id));
    modelMap.addAttribute("webPost", new WebPost());
    return "people/createPost";
}

@PostMapping("/{id}") 
public String postUserPost(@ModelAttribute("webPost") @Valid WebPost webPost, BindingResult bindingResult,
                           @PathVariable("id") int id) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return "people/{id}/createPost";
    webPost.setId_note(1);
    webPost.setData_pub(new Date());
    return  "redirect:/people/{id}"; //"people/test";
}
```

When I launch it in browser (localhost:8080/people/0/createPost), the first controller works well. When I submit empty Form and bindingResult.hasErrors()==true (in second Controller), it forwards in the Browser to localhost:8080/people/0 instead of to the same page and gets 500 error.
If I fill out the Form, it is also redirected to localhost:8080/people/0 and also gives an error 500.

Controller, where it redirects

```
@GetMapping("/{id}") 
    public String showBlog (@PathVariable ("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap1){ 
        modelMap1.addAttribute("person", personDao.getPersonById(id));
        modelMap1.addAttribute("userDB", personDao.getUsrById(id));
        modelMap1.addAttribute("webPost", new WebPost());
        return ("people/blog");
    }
```

works well If I update browser by hands on the link localhost:8080/people/0 or go to it from the HTML link. But fails, when redirected to it from PostMapping controller.
What's wrong with it?

Project pushed on github: over here is [controller](https://github.com/Kozlachkov/blog/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kozlachkov/controllers/MainControllers.java), and the [form](https://github.com/Kozlachkov/blog/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/people/createPost.html)

Upd: IDEA says the wrong return template. What will be correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a different way for the redirect.
Maybe something like this where you use HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect:

```java
    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public void handleFoo(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/foobar");
    }

    @GetMapping("/foobar")
    public String handleFooBar() {
        return "FooBar!";
    }
```

Comment: Thank's for attempt to help! I figured out, that it does not work, when I insert a Number somewhere in a middle in the path: String str3 = "/people/"+id+"/createPost". (and return str3) If the number goes at the last position it works, if in the middle it fails.  Would you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Abandon my question! I'm an idiot! In returning String should not be mentioned number, just simple string  "/people/createPost"

Comment: For newbies like me advise in case of similar problems: 1) All links should be directional (start from "/"), not relative; 2) Check fild's names coincidence in DB and in Models; 3) use method Post instead of Get, otherwise you will receive "?" sign at the end of the link and Controller will not read it for second shot; 4) check for absence of "/" at the end of return link; 5) check that you filled similar Model or ModelMap (as in regular Constructor) before returning this page.